# jquery autocomplete select event is not working in jquery 1.4.4 version

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-1.4

jquery autocomplete select event is not working in jquery 1.4.4 version.
i've requirement like, on select i need to do something

```
//this is the code iam using
$("#keyword").autocomplete('/topic/newSearchAjax', {
                    matchSubset : false,
                     select: function (a,b) {
                         $(this).val(b.item.value);
                            console.log(this);
                            alertMsg(value)
                        }
                });
```

if it doesn't support in 1.4.4 is there any alternative to get this functionality?

Comment: If jquery version is the case... Why can't u use latest jquery version

Answer (score 0):

refer this fiddle [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EBduF/627/) see if it helps.

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
 source: function( req, resp ) {
    $.post( "/echo/json/", {
        json: '["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]',            
        delay: 1
    }, function(data) {
        resp( data );
    }, "JSON" );
 },
 select: function (event, ui) {
    alert(ui.item.label);
    return false;
 }    
});
```

HTML:

```
<input id="autocomplete">
```